# Powershell checking inside a file for text in a variable but ignoring whitespace

Tags: powershell, select-string

What I'm trying to do using PowerShell is to search a config file for a string of text with random amount of whitespace or tabs

Using

```
$mytext = '<add name="MyName"
                dllPath="My.dll"
                className="MyClass" />'
Select-String -Path $myfile -Pattern $mytext
```

I thought `.replace(' ' , '')` might help with the view of just taking the whitespace out. I then thought, there are loads of smarter people than me on here!

Thanks in advance

Natty

Comment: 3 points. `Select-String` uses regular expressions and you have control characters in your sample text that __need to be escaped__. Second `\s+` is a regex that would match variable whitespace. Where in that text are you expecting whitespace... between the attributes? Last: If this is XML or HTML you should be using a parser that would account for this for you

Comment: You should write a multiline regex that'll have `\s+` in all places where you expect whitespace in the file text. Then read your file as a single string and try matching with regexp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank for the pointers folks.

From the info you both supplied I'm now loading an xml into a variable and parsing it.

```
[xml]$myfile = Get-Content "c:\myfile.config"
```

You can then use this to check it

```
IF ($myfile.name -match $matchnametothis) {Write-Host "do something exciting here"}
```

Thanks again, and hope this helps others.

Natty

Answer (score 0):

If your whitespace can contain newlines, as it appears to, then I don't think you can do this with `Select-String`.  It appears to check your pattern on a line-by-line basis which won't work if your pattern needs to span lines. In this case, you can use `Get-Content` to read the whole file as a single string and the `-match` operator e.g.:

```
Get-Content .\file.txt -Raw | Where {$_ -match '(?s)(name.*?dllPath)'} |
    Foreach {$matches[1]}
```

Note that the regex pattern uses `singleline` or dot matches anything mode via this directive `(?s)`.